# Import error with django/python script

Tags: django, django-models, import, python-import

I am trying to run this script that will generate some fake data for my model but I am running into an import error : `ImportError: No module named apps.photos.models`

This is my project setup:

```
Project Folder/
              apps/
                  photos/
                    __init__.py
                    models.py
                    ...
             utils/
                  __init__.py
                  fake_data.py
                  ...
             __init__.py
             manage.py
             settings.py
             urls.py
             ...
```

These are my imports for fake_data.py

```
import os, sys
script_path = os.path.abspath(__file__)
sys.path.append(script_path)

import random

from loremipsum.generator import *

from apps.photos.models import Photo
```

I dont know why Im not able to import the Photo model. Am im adding the file to the python path correctly? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to add the parent directory of `apps` to the path if you want to be able to import `apps`.

Also remember to set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable if it's a stand alone script.

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'
```